# Empty cell in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

There is a usual flexbox with the elements:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.flexbox__item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
</div>
```

How to insert an empty cell in this flexbox after `.offset-*` without using additional markup and *after* with *before*?

Those. It is necessary that it come out like this, but without specifying the width of the blocks. Only flex-grow

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.flexbox__item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  width: 25%;
}

.offset-1 {
  margin-right: calc(25% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
</div>
```

The number of cells is unknown. `Offset-1` means that you need to make an empty one cell,`offset-2` means two cell, and so on.

Comment: So we cannot add any items, cannot use `::after` or `::before`, and cannot use `width`?

Comment: @Michael_B, yep :)

Comment: Then the only way to create the offset space would be `margin`, and that would interfere with `flex-grow`. Not sure flexbox is your solution here.

Comment: @Michael_B, this is bad. Then I will look for a different approach

Comment: Based on what I know right now, I can't think of a way to make this work with your restrictions and flexbox. Maybe somebody else sees a way. Good luck.

Comment: @Michael_B, the only option that I came up with. This is to set the width manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with additional wrappers - the wrappers will grow, and the cell elements inside the growing wrappers will occupy 1/2, 1/3, etc. of the width of the wrappers.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}

.flexbox__item {
  margin: 3px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexbox__item-inner {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.offset-1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.offset-1 .flexbox__item-inner {
  width: 50%;
}

.offset-2 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.offset-2 .flexbox__item-inner {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-2">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```